# Dolby surround format in iTunes HD movie downloads

Tags: video, itunes, itunes-store, dolby

I'm trying to determine what the format is of audio tracks stored in iTunes HD movie downloads. For example, on the iTunes store page for "Star Wars: The Force Awakens" (https://itunes.apple.com/gb/movie/star-wars-the-force-awakens/id1063948707) the audio language is listed as "English (Dolby 5.1, Subtitles, CC), which I would expect to be something like a Dolby AC-3 track. However, after downloading, `mediainfo` lists the audio track as:

```
Audio #1
ID                                       : 2
Format                                   : AAC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Audio Codec
Format profile                           : LC
Codec ID                                 : 40
Duration                                 : 2h 18mn
Source duration                          : 2h 18mn
Bit rate mode                            : Variable
Bit rate                                 : 160 Kbps
Maximum bit rate                         : 269 Kbps
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Channel positions                        : Front: L R
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 KHz
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 156 MiB (3%)
Source stream size                       : 156 MiB (3%)
Title                                    : Core Media Audio
Language                                 : English
Encoded date                             : UTC 2016-03-22 15:35:19
Tagged date                              : UTC 2016-03-22 15:36:39
Encryption                               : iTunes
```

Is this how audio tracks for iTunes HD movies are provided, as something like an AAC-encoded Dolby Pro Logic II, which doesn't feel like a genuine representation of saying the language is Dolby 5.1? Or is something amiss here with my download?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be the result of using mediainfo on a still-encrypted version of the file, to which it presumably can't determine the audio encoding correctly. It works as expected and shows a Dolby Digital 5.1 track during playback.